# Count number of asserts executed when running py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

When I run `pytest` on file like

```
 test_a(): ...
 test_b(): ...
```

The output will include

```
... === 2 passed in 3.1415 seconds === ...
```

I would like to know how many `asserts` have been tested, as one `test_()` function might have had multiple generated (for example in a for loop), when testing new, faster implementation against slow, reference implementation of unit tested function.

Comment: As test cases are written by yourself and with known input it should be easy to count assertions yourself and print that. But i doubt, that this is useful. Unit test are mainly there for testing your logic not the execution speed. Thats why you should keep them small and simple without any fancy looping.

Comment: I need that not for benchmarking but rather to test multiple corner cases in  one test. I don't think it's wise to split one logical thing to test into multiple differest test functions ...

Comment: It is wise. If it's not possible to do this chances are the method you are testing does too many things at once. It's much better to have a single test case for every corner case. You'll immediately see what went wrong if it fails. If you test multiple cases in one test you may have to debug again. If the assertions really belong to one logical unit you can of course just put them into one test. But why do you want to count them then?